# Trying to run Python executable using Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm manually running a Python script, which pushes data in a DataFrame to Google Big Query, and everything works fine, but only when I run it in Spyder.  When I created an executable to do the same, and run the executable by invoking Google Cloud Scheduler, I get this error message:

```
'pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-bigquery' distribution was not found and is required by the application'
```

So, I run this:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
```

Then, I get 'requirement already satisfied' message.  It seems like the library is installed, but no matter what I do, I can't get it to run without manually triggering the job.  I want to run this executable using Google Cloud Scheduler.  has anyone encountered this before?  Any thoughts as to what to do to get thi working?  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide us with your exact steps to reproduce this error, so that we have more context to assist you with.

Comment: where are you running the pip install command? is it in your cloud shell?

Comment: Hummm, actually that was a local pip install.  You raised an excellent point.  Let me look into this and I'll follow up with my findings in just a bit.

Comment: Ok, I just re-ran 'pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery' in the GCP environment.  All requirements are satisfied.  Now, I open the Anaconda cmd prompt and enter cd to navigate to the directory with the exe file.  Then, finally, I enter this: 'Testing.exe' (this is the actual name of the executable that I'm trying to run).  Now, I get this message: 'pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-bigquery' distribution was not found and is required by the application'

Comment: How are you invoking the executable via Cloud Scheduler?